# Integrated Security with username and password

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is it possible to use Integrated Security with username and password 
for connection to SQL Server database because I am using one feature called as Filestream which uses only Integrated Security.

Comment: Hi! Here is a similiar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752084/sql-server-integrated-security

Comment: Can you provide some more details?