# Build SQL Connection string with integrated security for use over VPN?

Tags: .net, sql, winforms, connection-string

I have Winforms application that connects to a SQL database. We are changing the connection strings so that they will now use integrated security (Windows Authentication) instead of SQL authentication. We have a few cases where people use the application over a VPN on their home computer.

Connecting to the database with SQL authentication isn't a problem over the VPN. I was wondering if there was a way in .NET to build a connection string with user's Windows Credentials specified to connect to the SQL database.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671904/connect-to-sql-via-windows-authentification-over-vpn) question. But the application I'm working with is a Click-Once application. And I'm unsure if this will work. I'm hoping for a solution that will require little-to no effort on the part of the end-user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VPN is a red herring. The issue is that the user is not logged in under the same domain as the SQL Server. The same issue would arise with any non-domain-joined PC, whether on a VPN or not.

1. You could join the PC to the domain. This is the best solution.
2. You could use the Legacy method - create matching usernames and passwords. However you then need to make sure they stay in sync.
3. You could use the NET USE command or `NetUseAdd` API to log in to the domain after connecting to the VPN.

See this question for more:

- This is the best one for you to use: [SQL Server Integrated Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752084/sql-server-integrated-security/10752761#10752761)
- But see also this one: [SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Runas user on different domain over VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237654/sql-server-management-studio-2008-runas-user-on-different-domain-over-vpn/5362712#5362712)