# Cannot connect to local instance of SQL Server Epxress after upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-10, sql-server-express

The title pretty much says it all, however let me tell you what I have researched.

I have verified that the following services ARE running ...

- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server Browser
- SQL Server VSS Writer
  (I don't really know what this one does)

This one however will not start ... For some reason it starts then automatically turns off.

- SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)

When I try to connect using my ***server_name\instance***  and Windows Authentication I get the following error ...

> "*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server)"*

The connection specified in the "Connect to Server" box was working perfectly fine before I upgraded. I thought it might have been my Norton 360 Premier but I uninstalled it and it didn't help. I AM having issues with the adapter frequently dropping the internet connection but I just disconnect and reconnect and that resolves itself ... perhaps it's related?

The other technique I tried was to replace the server name with the IP address ... ***192.168.0.22\Instance*** ... This actually seemed to find the SQL Server but rejected the Windows Authentication ...

> *"Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication."*

Any help getting this up and running would be greatly appreciated. I have several databases on here and would hate to have to reinstall SQL Server and manually hook them back up .. or worse lose any of them. I have a client waiting so ... the sooner I get help the MORE appreciative I'll be!!

Sincerely,

G

**UPDATE**

I have access! But I am not sure what I did that made the difference.

- Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- Expand SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32-bit)
- Select "Aliases"
- Choose alias name ".\SQLEXPRESS"
- Change alias name to "192.168.0.2\SQLEXPRESS" (using your IP address)
- Change the value of "Server" to 192.168.0.2\SQLEXPRESS (using your IP address)

This allowed me to log on to the server using the ".\SQLEXPRESS" alias.

Some things I do NOT understand however is ...

- I changed the "alias name" expecting that to appear in my list of connections drop down in SQL Management Studio. It did not, but the alias "'\SQLEXPRESS" was still there and worked!
- For the alias "SERVER\SQLEXPRESS" I changed the "Server" value to use the IP address as well but received the authentication error described earlier, even though the only difference was the Alias Name.

Comment: Sql server configuration services stop and start.

Comment: Does your hosts file (`\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) contain any name to ip translations?

Comment: Anyway you can regain access to the server using a single user mode. Read [microsoft's instruction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx) or [article with pictures](http://www.top-password.com/blog/2-methods-to-start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode/)

Comment: Thank you for your responses ... Denish -I have restarted the services several times. In fact the machine has been rebooted several times as well. @Dmitry - The hosts file contains NO translations. I have also added the "-m"  to the start up parameters of the SQL Service but am still unable to connect using the server name and still get the same authentication error when using the IP address.

Comment: The difference is you accessed a file share on the machine, probably using Explorer to browse the machine, and probably entered the password there. This established a NETBIOS session. Your integrated authentication then succeeded because you had a session.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14400823/build-sql-connection-string-with-integrated-security-for-use-over-vpn/14403443#14403443