# excel to sql connection failure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sharepoint-2010

I have 2 different servers on my hyper v, i have sql on one and i have SharePoint on the other.  i am trying to create a connection to a sql server table from the server that contains SharePoint. To import data into excel as a table or pivot table report.After entering the sql server name and trying to connect by using window authentication, this error keeps coming up : login failed. the login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication. The Sql server is 2008.

Any idea of what i can do to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Show some code or queries showing the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Integrated security can work with non-trusted domains and non-matching usernames and passwords. This may help you in your scenario.

The solution in these problems may help:

- This is the best one for you to use: [SQL Server Integrated Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752084/sql-server-integrated-security/10752761#10752761)
- But see also this one: [SQL Server Management Studio 2008 Runas user on different domain over VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237654/sql-server-management-studio-2008-runas-user-on-different-domain-over-vpn/5362712#5362712)

Comment: not working, maybe i'm doing something wrong. I was told the network path was not found. what i did: i typed in NET USE \\DBSERVER /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME. on the server containing sharepoint

Comment: @user2164730, try the full name of the DBSERVER - whatever name you use to try to connect to SQL.